# Using sleep in VB.net while running external process

Tags: python, vb.net

I have a problem with running a Python script in VB.net because the .net program runs up the CPU usage. In essence, I execute a Python script from within a VB.net program, re-direct the standard output so what the Python script prints gets caught by .net.

```
                Dim python_handler As New PythonHandler
                python_handler.Execute("python.exe", "my_script.py")

                ' Wait for python_handler to get back data
                While python_handler.pythonOutput = String.Empty

                End While

                Dim pythonOutput As String = python_handler.pythonOutput
```

Here PythonHandler is a class and its Execute function looks like:

```
Public Sub Execute(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal arguments As String)
    If _process IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("Already watching process")
    End If
    _process = New Process()
    _process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
    _process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
    _process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    _process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    _process.Start()
    _process.BeginOutputReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub _process_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles _process.OutputDataReceived
    If _process.HasExited Then
        _process.Dispose()
        _process = Nothing
    End If
    RaiseEvent OutputRead(e.Data)
End Sub

Private Sub textProcessing_OutputRead(ByVal output As String) Handles Me.OutputRead
    outputFetched = True
    pythonOutput = output
End Sub
```

The problem is the While loop which exists because it waits for the Python script to finish. The CPU runs up to 100%. I tried putting a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) in the While loop, but then the .net program fails to catch the Python output, nothing gets returned. Could it be because Process.BeginOutputReadLine() is asynchronous?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Slippery Petes answer... whenever you employ asynchronous methodologies, it almost never correct to use polling loops to wait for results.  The following line is very processor intensive and defeats the performance benefits of using asynchronous methods.

```
While python_handler.pythonOutput = String.Empty
End While
```

If you ever find yourself using a polling loop, you should ask yourself if there is an event driven way to handle this problem or in this case a proper way to wait for the event.

```
_process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced thw While loop with an event driven way (using Threading.AutoResetEvent).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `_process_OutputDataReceived` is being assigned to the `_process.OutputDataReceived` event.  You should assign this before starting the process, then call `_process.WaitForExit()` instead of your while loop.  It should block automatically until the process is done.  At least my C# test did.

```
_process = New Process()
_process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath
_process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
AddHandler _process.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf _process_OutputDataReceived
_process.Start()
_process.BeginOutputReadLine()
_process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: In class definition of PythonHandler:Private WithEvents _process As Process. The sub _process_OutputDataReceived has the Handles _process.OutputDataReceived in the function head. I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I have made the alterations you suggested, and after some testing I noticed that OutPutDataReceived event gets called twice, once with an empty string. I'll do some more tweaking.

Comment: Hi, Because the OutPutDataRecevied event gets raised twice I find that I must use a While loop to check when the process has exited. In the OutPutDataRecevied handler I have a check which checks if the process has exited or not, and if it has I set a boolean variable to True. But this means that OutPutDataRecevied gets called before the process has exited, because it executes twice and only the second time around the process has been exited.

Comment: Hi, I might have found a better solution to the problem. Instead of using a While loop with Sleep I pass an AutoResetEvent object to the PythonHandler class. The PythonHandler class then signals the event when it has finished and the calling thread can continue. Dim resetEvent As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

Dim python_handler As New PythonHandler(resetEvent)
python_handler.Execute("python.exe", "my_script.py")

resetEvent.WaitOne() ' Blocks current thread of execution until the WaitHandle recevies a signal